# Firebase sharing resources across multiple html pages

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Please I am currently working on a project with firebase using it as my backend . So I have page which is user. Html and another page which is sign.html and that page is connected to the firebase  services but I want to share firebase configuration across these pages . So I would like to know for each of these pages do I need to create separate configurations ? And if not how do I now share these resources from firebase with these separate html pages because anytime I try doing it I usually get errors . So please I need a guidance on how to go about this  Please assist

I tried sharing configurations between these html pages and I am getting errors please help me